# Error in a code to calculate the max and min in a set of inputed numbers

Tags: python-3.x

This is a simple code to calculate max and min values in a set of inputed numbers, the code keeps taking an input from the user until the user enters "done", this is when the loop breaks and the code prints the max and min it calculated.
The problem is, i get an error in line 5, is there something wrong in this block of code? 
if num=='done':
    break
because this is the line that gives me error and i can't see anything wrong with it.

```py
largest = -1
smallest = None
while True:
    num = input('Enter a number: ')
    if num == 'done':
        break
    try:
        n=float(num)
    except: 
        print("Invalid input")
        continue
    if largest ==-1:
        largest = n
    elif n>largest:
        largest=n

    if smallest is None:
        smallest=n

    elif n<smallest:
        smallest=n

print("Maximum is", largest)
print("Minimum is", smallest)
```

the code doesn't execute and gives an error at line 5 
ParseError: bad input on line 5

Comment: Please include the full error message.

Comment: `elif num>largest:` to  `elif n>largest:` ; change for smallest too

Comment: okay i changed num to n, but i still get the error at line 5..
i am writing the code from a browser tool and the error just says: "Bad input in line 5"

Comment: What is this "browser tool" you're using?  It may require that you enter the program's input before you run it.

Comment: It's PY4E..and no it requires input only when i run the code

Comment: Do they specify an input format? (And if so, paste it into your question verbatim?)

Comment: No they don't specify anything. You just write the code, then press "Check Code" and the code runs. and when a line that requires input comes in, a window pops up and you just enter your input.

Comment: The problem is not with the input, it's specifically on line 5. You see, the code doesn't even execute or require input, it just blows up from the beginning, saying that there is something wrong with line 5.

Comment: Gah... "Bad input" is so ambiguous. :( Random guess: Try retyping your code, and make sure that *all* the indents are spaces (no tabs).

Comment: Alright thank you, i will do that hopefully it works

Comment: The code is just fine and worked for me without any problem

Comment: Then the problem is with the tool i am using and not the syntax. Thank you.